# Can FCM notification use `plurals` on Android for localizable title or body?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The Firebase payload doc shows localizable titles

> title_loc_key     Optional, string
>
> The key to the title string in the app's string resources to use to
>   localize the title text to the user's current localization.

Does anyone know if using a `plurals` resource will work? If there is no `string` resource perhaps, just maybe it will try `plurals` (getQuantityString)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests run using version 10.2.6 of the Firebase libs indicate that the resource specified by `title_loc_key` or `body_loc_key` must be a `string` resource.  `plurals` resources are not searched when the message is received.

In my test, when a `plurals` tag was provided in the message for `title_loc_key` or `body_loc_key`  a warning message was logged:

```
W/FirebaseMessaging: title_loc_key resource not found: myPluralsTitle Default value will be used

W/FirebaseMessaging: body_loc_key resource not found: myPluralsBody Default value will be used
```

Comment: OK, yet another reason to use data message, for now.